# Invoking controller action on dropdownlist change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

the below code works but but the problem with this code is that every time it onchange event fired it looses the session/viewbag data to null and I'm looking into a different approach where I should be able to invoke on when the user change anything in the dropdownlist and also pass the value to the controller without loosing my session/viewbag data.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Company, 
    new SelectList(
       (System.Collections.IEnumerable)
       ViewBag.DropDownCompanyName, 
       "Value", "Text"), 
    new { 
      @class = "form-control", 
      onchange = 
          "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' +  
           this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" 
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are thinking of the original ASP.NET Model, where the framework rehydrates a Session for every user request, for example when a DropDownList fires an OnChange post back.

Mvc does not work this way; **there is no persistent Session**.

Instead you're responsible for maintaining the state yourself, or architecting around it.  For example, you can serialize the data you need into a hidden field above the Drop Down, and then append it into the url:

```
<input type='hidden' id='state' value=@Model.SomeSerializedState />
@Html.DropDownListFor(... 
       onchange = "document.location.href = /url/?c=" + 
                  this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + 
                  "&state=" + $('#state').value;
```

Or you can architect around it.  Since you are loading data specific to the value in the Drop Down List, you might be able to just load that data using an Ajax call and update your page DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: I think you mean "viewstate" instead of "session". MVC supports the session very well.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I meant persistent server side session.  So MVC doesn't have a concept of keeping a 'session' in between user requests.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It does, MVC controllers expose a Session property... I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, but I don't agree with what you're saying about the session.

Comment: Perhaps SessionState would be the more appropriate term then?